# How does Web Browser open offline ip address just like Jupyter notebook?

Tags: django, networking, server, client, jupyter

I was using **Jupyter** notebook and was wandering how does it works offline. Where does server is? How TCP connection is made? How does htpp request is sent?

Similarly when we are working on some website project (eg: making one website in django) when you compile that html code in your terminal, it provides you an output with an ip address and when you run that ip address in your browser, browser will show you your website. So how does this work and how that ip address it generated? Can anybody please explain me?

Answer (score 1):

1. The browser sends a Http request to the server.
2. The server does its magic and dumps the request via the CGI to django.
3. Some part of django receives the request and turns it into a django request object.
4. The request object wanders on some nebulous paths through the middleware which does strange things with it.
5. The request object finally ends up in some function which looks at the urls, takes the patterns out of urls.py and calls up a view function.
6. The view functions do their magic (with models and templates as partners) in, this is probably where I have the strongest illusion of understanding (well, apart from the database abstraction magic, that is... ;)
7. The view functions returns an HttpResponse object, I guess this is returned on some nebulous paths to the CGI.
8. Webserver takes over again and sends the Http response to the client.